# How to use modules in c++ 20 using g++?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, c++-modules

I read this link **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules** and tried to copy the following example from this website. I already knew that this compiler partially supports the module system. *(Note: I used windows)*

```cpp
// hello.cc
module;
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
export module hello;
export void greeter(std::string_view const &name) {
  std::cout << "Hello " << name << "!\n";
}
```

```cpp
// main.cc
import hello;
int main() {
  greeter("world");
  return 0;
}
// Should print "Hello world!"
```

I currently have **GCC 11.0.1** snapshot and tried to compile these files using the following arguments:
`g++ -std=gnu++2b -Wall -fmodules-ts hello.cc main.cc` and the compiler gave me these errors:

```
hello.cc:6:8: internal compiler error: in get_cxx_dialect_name, at cp/name-lookup.c:7027
    6 | export module hello;
      |        ^~~~~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
In module imported at main.cc:1:1:
hello: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
hello: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/hello.gcm'
hello: note: imports must be built before being imported
hello: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

If I compile first the `hello.cc`, then the compiler still gave errors:

```cpp
C:\...\hello.cc | 6 | error: failed to write compiled module: No such file or directory |
C:\...\hello.cc | 6 | note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/hello.gcm' |
```

- What should I do?
- Should I just wait for the full support for modules in g++?
- Is there any other way to use it even though g++ partially supports it?

Comment: I believe that this is https://gcc.gnu.org/PR99436 and was fixed in https://gcc.gnu.org/g:bc56d27de97ecea813279ce5ba45b278dcccfe21. Not sure when mingw will catch up.

Comment: i already added the `std=gnu++2b` option or `std=c++2b`

Comment: I mean gcc modules do not support c++2b before this comment.

Comment: ...oh ... i see

Comment: It looks like it just wants the `gcm.cache` directory to exist, and it didn’t (either because it doesn’t know to create it or failed to do so).

Comment: With GCC 11.1, your example compiles without problem. Maybe a bug corrected since?

Comment: @informaticienzero which compiler options do i need in order to work? i only turned on `-fmodules-ts`

Comment: I just tried the example in the link you [shared](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) and it worked perfectly for me on manjaro linux. Maybe try with linux on a VM? Alternatively for windows maybe you can try on VC++?

Answer (score 3):

I hit a similar problem when upgrading an existing project. The issue is related to the file extension, ensure you have named the compilation unit as `hello.cpp`.

```
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ g++ -fmodules-ts hello.mpp main.cpp
In module imported at main.cpp:1:1:
hello: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
hello: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/hello.gcm’
hello: note: imports must be built before being imported
hello: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ mv hello.mpp hello.cpp
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ g++ -fmodules-ts hello.cpp main.cpp
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ ./a.out
Hello world!
```

Additionally, I hit an issue when attempting to rename the file back to `hello.mpp` to see the original error; removing `gcm.cache/` folder fixed it.

```
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ mv hello.cpp hello.mpp
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ g++ -fmodules-ts hello.mpp main.cpp
/usr/bin/ld:hello.mpp: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:hello.mpp:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ rm -rf gcm.cache
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ g++ -fmodules-ts hello.cpp main.cpp
bcrowhurst@pop-os:/tmp$ ./a.out
Hello world!
```

It appears g++-11.1 has a restriction (by design?) when scanning for module compilation units. Which the C++20 specification does not concern itself.

**Links**

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4720.pdf

Comment: Note that `.mpp` is not in the list of [recognized file extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options). So you need to use `-x c++` in that case before specifying file name.