# Vector in C++ module causes useless Bad file data GCC output

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, c++20

**TL;DR:** [GCC 11.2.0 (image `f7ea55625e09`)](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gcc/library/gcc/bullseye/images/sha256-f7ea55625e097107d176d06641b637eeae64c606dbf9fa2938872e4c0aca15bc?context=explore) + C++20 + [`<vector>`'s `std::vector<anything>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) cause useless output. How to get out something I can work with?

Compilation works in:

- module cache
- single file
- separate module file

```
In module imported at main.cpp:4:1: import mymodule;
mymodule: error: failed to read compiled module: Bad file data eh???????
mymodule: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/mymodule.gcm' exists, 124 912 Bytes 
mymodule: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue ????????
compilation terminated.
```

For the `fatal` (gate) I found only these references ([1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102525), [2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98944)), from which everything looks okay for my case.

---

I've tried various simple things with the new C++ modules (C++20, GCC 11.2) and it makes me wonder whether I'm just encountering a compiler bug / missing implementation or not getting something very simple.

Here is a simple C++ code with `vector<string>`, it compiles just fine with basic flags and outputs what's expected:

```sh
# create module cache for system headers
for item in iostream string vector
do
    g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header $item
done
```

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts main.cpp
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <vector>;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = std::vector<std::string>{};
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");

    for (auto& item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
Hello
world
```

Here I move the vector creation into a new function, compiles fine, works fine. Still no separate module except for the system headers.

```cpp
// main.cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <vector>;

std::vector<std::string> create() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = std::vector<std::string>{};
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = create();

    for (auto& item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here I move the function to a separate, exported function in a separate module file.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c mymodule.cpp
```

```cpp
// mymodule.cpp
export module mymodule;
import <string>;
import <vector>;

export std::vector<std::string> create() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = std::vector<std::string>{};
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");
    return vec;
}
```

which compiles just fine, but when adding to the `main.cpp`,

```cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <vector>;
import mymodule;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = create();

    for (auto& item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get only this:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts mymodule.cpp main.cpp
```

```
In module imported at main.cpp:4:1: import mymodule;
mymodule: error: failed to read compiled module: Bad file data eh???????
mymodule: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/mymodule.gcm' exists, 124 912 Bytes 
mymodule: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue ????????
compilation terminated.
```

```
# file gcm.cache/mymodule.gcm
ELF 32-bit LSB no file type, no machine, version 1 (SYSV)
# file gcm.cache/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream.gcm
ELF 32-bit LSB no file type, no machine, version 1 (SYSV)
# file a.out
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

And it doesn't seem to be a problem with simple containers nor with the `import` declarations of the `<vector>` alone:

```cpp
// mymodule.cpp
export module mymodule;
import <string>;
import <vector>;

export std::string create() {
    return "world";
}

// main.cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <vector>;
import mymodule;

int main() {
    std::string vec = create();
    std::cout << vec << std::endl;
}
```

And I've tried playing with (and with no real effect):

- `.cpp` vs `.mpp` extensions, though it shouldn't matter
- clearing the cache before each compilation ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67030839/5994041))
- [`global module fragment (7)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) placement i.e. `module; [stuff]; export module mymodule;`
- compiling separately (`-c mymodule.cpp` + `-c main.cpp`) to link manually (fails the same way on `main.cpp`)
- (re)moving `export` from the function
- not calling the function, just importing (`import mymodule;` to trigger compilation)
- switching from `std::vector<std::string>` to `std::vector<int>` to see whether the template's argument list causes the problem
- switching from `std::vector<std::string>` to `std::pair<int, int>` and then to `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` (with `<utility>` header module cache) to see whether just `<vector>` is broken for me

And it looks like `<vector>` header is causing the problem. Any ideas how can I pry open GCC to give me something better than "naaah, can't do"? At the least I can generate assembly with `-S` (3k+ lines) or use `hexdump` / `objdump` for `gcm.cache/mymodule.gcm` and look at the binary, but I'm not sure what to look for because of the useless output.

**Edit:** It looks like a problem with the architectures perhaps?

- using `-m64` does nothing for the module cache, remains 32bit
- using `-m32` (`apk install -y g++-multilib` on 64bit) returns the same output

**Edit 2:** So I rewrote it a bit to make it compatible with Clang 12 (`b978a93`) with a help of [this article](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/11/07/modular-hello-world/#furthermore-once-vendors-support) but it's not 1:1 and is rather kind of butchering (`string_view` note), but maybe I'm not seeing the broader picture or something is missing.

I don't think I should be including `<string_view>` though as that should have been included automatically. Otherwise even if I write my module, I can just start copy-pasting every `#include` from the implementation until there's none left so I can ensure the file order (then again what'd be the module's point).

```cpp
// mymodule.cpp
module;
// no proper "import" available yet, so switching to the old includes
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
export module mymodule;

export std::vector<std::string> create() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = std::vector<std::string>{};
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");
    return vec;
}

// need to wrap printing for a string_view for some reason
export void printme(std::string &item) {
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
// includes needed for "auto" and usage of those types
// and were needed also for print(create()) call
// so something seems broken over here
#include <vector>
#include <string>
import mymodule;

int main() {
    auto vec = create();
    for (std::string item : vec) {
        // string_view:142:2: note: declaration of
        // 'basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>' does not match
        // std::cout << item << std::endl;
        printme(item);
    }
}
```

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -c mymodule.cpp -Xclang -emit-module-interface -fimplicit-modules -fimplicit-module-maps -o mymodule.pcm
clang++ -std=c++20 -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fimplicit-modules -fimplicit-module-maps mymodule.cpp main.cpp
```

So the issue seems to be GCC specific and most likely is a bug judging by the architecture switching (hardcoding/wrong code branch in GCC?). Maybe worth revisiting after `>11.2.0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67030839/681865

Comment: Pure speculation: Could the module have been compiled in x86 mode instead of x64 mode?

Comment: @talonmies yeah, I've seen that one and tried everything suggested over there too. :/ Adding to the question as a ref.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it's in 32bit and `a.out` in 64bit. But that doesn't seem to impact it for the `std::pair` swap.

Comment: What happens if you compile it in x64 mode instead? I'm really not very experienced when it comes to modules, but I expect it'll be closer to what you need.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Seems like a hardcoded arch within GCC to me? `-m64` does nothing for the module cache and `-m32` returns the same output with `Bad file data`.

Comment: @PeterBadida Darn... Have you tried it with other compilers? `modules` are pretty new and I expect that the level of standard compliance isn't 100% in every compiler.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I haven't tried with others, but I have found a Docker image with clang 12. Just some simple commands for compiling the module resulted in `gthr-default.h` and `weakref declaration must have internal linkage`, so I'll get some sleep and try to check again with a clear head tomorrow. I'll update the question. Maybe it's just GCC specific, perhaps a regression or something. Except possible clang++ alternative, I don't have access to other compilers, so suggestions are welcome. The modules have quite a pull, it'd be nice to have them working. :)

Comment: I can confirm this issue on `alpine:20220316` with `gcc version 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219)`.
Few notes:
1. It is a member of a struct with of `std::vector<std::string_view>`
2. `std::vector<int>` is OK
3. `std::vector<std::string>` is NOK
4. `std::vector<empty_class_in_same_module>` is NOK
5. `using simple_type_alias=std::vector<std::string_view>` is NOK
6. `template<class t> struct vector_factory {using type=...};` is NOK
7. `std::deque<std::string_view>` is NOK
8. `std::list<std::string_view>` is NOK UPDATE: I think it is more related to `std::string_view, std::string, const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing a shared library using C++20 modules (gcc 11.2.0) and have the same "Bad file data" error for `std::vector` with custom type. In my case, as already mentioned by [@balázs-Árva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456868/vector-in-c-module-causes-useless-bad-file-data-gcc-output#comment127012949_70456868) this error occurs for most containers: maps, lists, etc.

Following your references I found [this issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98718) and now have a temporary solution with just this line in module.

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default){}
```

This works in my library with other containers. I've looked for a proper solution using compiler options but haven't any success.

Files / commands

```
// mymodule.cpp
export module mymodule;
import <string>;
import <vector>;

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default){}

export std::vector<std::string> create() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = std::vector<std::string>{};
    vec.push_back("Hello");
    vec.push_back("world");
    return vec;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <vector>;
import mymodule;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = create();
    for (auto& item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header iostream
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header string
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header vector
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 mymodule.cpp main.cpp
```

```
$ ./a.out 
Hello
world
```

P.S. I can't comment, so posted it as answer, hope it will bring up them.